# React - How to get state data from a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am just starting to learn react and I'm currently building a form, so far I've created a parent component 'Form' and I've separated the rest of the inputs as components and each component has its own state. My question is how to get that state data from the children's components and use it in the parent component 'Form' when submitting the form?

Here is my parent component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Name from "components/Name";
import Email from "components/Email";
import Select from "components/Select";
import Bio from "components/Bio";

class Form extends Component {
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="shape rectangle"></div>
                <div className="shape triangle"></div>
                <div className="shape circle"></div>
                <Name />
                <Email />
                <Select />
                <Bio />
                <button type="submit" className="btn">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

And one of the child component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Create Name component for name && email inputs
class Name extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
  }

  // Handle first name input on change event
  handleFirstNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    });
  };

  // Handle last name input on change event
  handleLastNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      lastName: event.target.value
    });
  };

  // Render labels and name inputs
  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="form-names">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">Name</label>
        <br/>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={firstName}
          placeholder="First Name"
          id="firstName"
          onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={lastName}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          id="lastName"
          onChange={this.handleLastNameChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Name;
```

Comment: Put the state in the parent, as well as the onChange-listeners, and pass them down to the childs as props

Comment: Will try that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you would need to "Lift the state" up to a common parent component (known as ancestor component), in your case, this would be the `<Form>` component. Then you would pass down the values to each corresponding child component as `props`.

It would look something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Name from "./Name";
// More imports go here..

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  // Handle first name input on change event
  handleFirstNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      firstName: event.target.value
    });
  };

  // Handle last name input on change event
  handleLastNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      lastName: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Name
          firstName={this.state.firstname}
          lastName={this.state.lastName}
          handleFirstNameChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}
          handleLastNameChange={this.handleLastNameChange}
        />
        {/* More components go here.. */}
        <p>Current state:</p>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lifting-state-up-qdtlu)

More info: [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) from the official React docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use something like [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), which would allow you to create a universal store and retrieve state from any component **or** create methods in your parent component, pass them down to it's children, and invoke them from within that child component. For example, you could have `handleFirstNameChange` in `Form` and pass it down to `Name`. In doing so you'd now keep props like `name` in `Form` as well and pass that down as well.

Comment: My react knowledge is still very basic and I am not familiar at all neither with context nor redux

Comment: If you're still new to React, they're pretty deep concepts to grasp overall. If you're interested, I'd read up on them and see if they suit your needs. In the meantime I'd just pass down my props as I've described from the parent to give you a basic understanding on how the concept of hierarchy works in this library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single state in the parent component , and pass the firstname and lastname in the props, your code will became:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Name from "components/Name";
import Email from "components/Email";
import Select from "components/Select";
import Bio from "components/Bio";

class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
   event.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Name onChange={this.onChange} firstName={this.state.firstName} lastName={this.state.lastName} />
        ...
        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Submit
        </button>
       </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Form;
```

and your child component became:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Create Name component for name && email inputs
class Name extends Component {


  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName , onChange} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="form-names">
        <label htmlFor="firstName">Name</label>
        <br/>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={firstName}
          placeholder="First Name"
          id="firstName"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={lastName}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          id="lastName"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is to do sth like the following, passing the data as props to the  component. But it doesn't make sense to me as when you click the submit button, the form gather data from the parent component. It may better keep the form in the parent component and group all the input data in state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Name from "components/Name";
import Email from "components/Email";
import Select from "components/Select";
import Bio from "components/Bio";

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        firstName = "",
        lastName = "",
        (and other input data you need)...
      }
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="shape rectangle"></div>
                <div className="shape triangle"></div>
                <div className="shape circle"></div>
                <Name firstName={this.state.firstName} lastName={this.state.lastName}/>
                <Email (inputData as props)/>
                <Select (inputData as props)/>
                <Bio (inputData as props)/>
                <button type="submit" className="btn">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```